# How to process a Celery task on a specific vhost?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Celery task like:

```
from celery.task import task
from django.conf import settings
from base.tasks import BaseTask

@task(name="throw_exception", base=BaseTask)
def print_value(*args, **kwargs):
    print('BROKER_URL:', settings.BROKER_URL)
```

and I'm running a Celery worker inside my virtualenv like:

```
celery worker -A myproject -l info
```

The Worker shows:

```
Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672/myapp
```

And when I launch my task from the Django shell with:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.BROKER_URL
'amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672/myapp'
>>> from myapp.tasks import print_value
>>> print_value.delay()
```

I never see the task executed in my worker's log.

However, if I instead change my worker to use a BROKER_URL with the default "/" vhost, then it immediately executes all the pending tasks, implying all my calls of `print_value.delay()` are sending it to the wrong vhost even though the correct BROKER_URL is set. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The problem seems to be Celery doesn't have a consistent @task decorator, and by using the wrong decorator, you disconnect the task from your broker settings. So essentially, all my tasks are configured to use the default broker, instead of the one defined in my settings. The old docs say to use `from celery.task import task` but the new docs...don't really specify, and seem to imply you should use the `app` instance defined in your `celery.py` file, like `@app.task`. The problem with this is that all my tasks are in separate `tasks.py` files, where they can't access the `app` instance. If I copy a task into my `celery.py` and use the `@app.task` decorator, then it uses the correct vhost and works as expected, but obvious, this isn't a practical fix, because I'd have to copy dozens of functions into this file. How do I fix this properly?

Comment: have your add vhost by `sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost {vhost_name}` and set user permissions to vhost by `sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p {vhost_name} {username} ".*" ".*" ".*"`?

Comment: @Ykh, Yes, it's not a rabbitmq issue.

Comment: you can try call task by request method in `views.py` not in python shell,not sure python shell use the same env as your virtualenv do.

Answer (score 4):

Having the same question for myself right now using Django + (Celery + RabbitMQ). My solution was,

`CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://<user>:<password>@localhost:5672/<vhost>`

Here's a detailed confirmation from RabbitMQ.com > Client Documentation > [RabbitMQ URI Specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html)

---

**For what it's worth...**

...there's a lot going on with Celery + RabbitMQ. I was looking at RabbitMQ with `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts`-- *and I don't see my vhost. WTF?* Finally, I realize I configured `supervisord` too early on my local development server. Starting Celery from the CLI gives a bunch of feedback that `supervisord` puts somewhere not directly under my nose, like:

`[2021-02-19 18:26:52,803: WARNING/MainProcess] (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.`

`AMQP` immediately reminded me of the connection string. Boom. There's your `vhost`.

Comment: FYI the documentation gives you an example URL with `pyamqp://USER:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME:PORT/` and i think the trailing `/` is done on purpose to indicate the rabbitmq vhost is `/` (rabbitmq always has the default vhost `/`).

Answer (score 1):

After digging through Celery's code, the only way I could find to set the current app was to call `celery._state._set_current_app(app)`. Obviously, this an internal method and not designed to be used this way, but I couldn't find any other way to explicitly set my custom app instance as the "current" app. I would have thought this should be done automatically, especially since my code is taken directly from the tutorial, so either the docs are incomplete or this is a bug.

In any case, the working celery file looks like:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
import os
import sys

from celery import Celery
from celery._state import _set_current_app
import django

app = Celery('myproject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
_set_current_app(app)

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.settings')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../myproject')))
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

That caused all the `@task` decorators in all my tasks.py files to correctly access my custom Celery instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a demo use djcelery with different vhost which is tested.

in your project folder,`__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

`celery.py`,replace `SchoolMS` with your own Project label:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery, platforms
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.  
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'SchoolMS.settings')

app = Celery('SchoolMS')
platforms.C_FORCE_ROOT = True

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to  
# pickle the object when using Windows.  
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

`settings.py`:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://schoolms:schoolms@localhost:5672/schoolms'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
}
```

`user/tasks.py`:

```
from celery import task

from django.conf import settings


@task
def send_tel_verify(tel_verify_id):
    try:
        tel_verify = TelVerify.objects.get(id=tel_verify_id)
        try:
            send_sms(tel_verify.tel, 'xxxx')
            return ''success'
        except SmsError as e:
            return 'error'
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return 'not found'
```

`user/views.py`

```
send_tel_verify.delay(tel_verify.id)
```